# Why do Eloquent has and whereHas methods use subqueries instead of joins?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Why does Laravel use subqueries for the Eloquent `has` and `whereHas` methods instead of using joins? For example, I have constructed an Eloquent query like this:

```
Order::whereHas('orderProducts', function($query)
{
        $query->where('product_id', $this->id);

})
->whereHas('status', function($query)
{
        $query->where('sales_data', 1);

})
->where('ext_created_at', '>=', $startDate)
->where('ext_created_at', '<=', $endDate.' 23:59:59')
->distinct()
->count('id');
```

The resulting query is:

```
select count(distinct `id`) as aggregate from `orders` where `orders`.`deleted_at` is null and (select count(*) from `order_products` where `order_products`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` and `product_id` = ? and `order_products`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1 and (select count(*) from `order_statuses` where `orders`.`order_status_id` = `order_statuses`.`id` and `sales_data` = ? and `order_statuses`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1 and `ext_created_at` >= ? and `ext_created_at` <= ?
```

This query returns a result of `16`. According to `DB::getQueryLog()`, this takes `23222.14 ms` to execute.

I then constructed another query like this:

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->leftJoin('order_products', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_products.order_id')
    ->leftJoin('order_statuses', 'orders.order_status_id', '=', 'order_statuses.id')
    ->whereNull('orders.deleted_at')
    ->where('order_products.product_id', $this->id)
    ->where('orders.ext_created_at', '>=', $startDate)
    ->where('orders.ext_created_at', '<=', $endDate.' 23:59:59')
    ->whereNull('order_products.deleted_at')
    ->where('order_statuses.sales_data', 1)
    ->distinct()
    ->count('orders.id')
```

The resulting query is:

```
select count(distinct `orders`.`id`) as aggregate from `orders` left join `order_products` on `orders`.`id` = `order_products`.`order_id` left join `order_statuses` on `orders`.`order_status_id` = `order_statuses`.`id` where `orders`.`deleted_at` is null and `order_products`.`product_id` = ? and `orders`.`ext_created_at` >= ? and `orders`.`ext_created_at` <= ? and `order_products`.`deleted_at` is null and `order_statuses`.`sales_data` = ?
```

This query also returns `16`, but takes `3.52 ms` to run.  Obviously, using joins has much better performance here, but is that only specific to my use case, or are joins generally better performance? If so, why wouldn't Eloquent use joins over subqueries? I would much rather work with models and make use of all the excellent Eloquent methods like `has` and `whereHas`, but the performance is so dramatically different that I am being forced to construct the query myself using the Query Builder.

Am I missing something here?

I am using `Laravel Framework version 4.2.16`.

Comment: You can add a lot of sub queries, but not joins. This is so to avoid clashes when the programmer uses a `join` and `whereHas` methods on the same relationship in one query. You could use aliases, but how far are you safe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you give me an example? Also, what do you mean by "but how far are you safe?".

Comment: In laravel, you can have multiple object chaining. E.g: `Car::whereHas('engine',function($q){return $q->whereHas('piston',function($q){return $q->whereHas('grease'......}});` You get the idea. Through the laravel implementation(subqueries), the scope of the queries are easily separated. Through joins, not so much. We also have to take into account that laravel abstracts all database implementations for us. Tomorrow, u wanna switch from mysql to postgres. Everything will work without a hitch. So, there's lots of factors to consider before implementation of joins for `whereHas` methods.

Comment: Unfortunately whereHas() approach leads to a deadend as soon as your database scales. 30k registered users and Mysql needs almost two minutes to filter their index view based on a composite many-to-many relationship constrains  using nested whereHas () clauses. Joins seems the only way to survive this...